# Login Form Not Working - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication, mysqli

I've got this login form not working - everything should be fine except that it always just says the login is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?
This is for a different project than yesterday's question but I did better coding in this one. Thanks for any help! By the way, this is the top part of login.php under this I have the HTML form based on Bootstrap.

```
<?php session_start();

require_once('db_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['formsubmit']))

{       
        $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
        $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
        $exists = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE email = '{$email}' AND pass = '{$pass}'"); 

        if(mysqli_fetch_array($exists, MYSQL_NUM) === 1)
        {
            if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
                setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], time()+60*60*24*365);
                setcookie('pass', md5($_POST['pass']), time()+60*60*24*365);

            } else {
                setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], false);
                setcookie('pass', md5($_POST['pass']), false);
            }

            header('Location: index.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: login.php?error=1');
        }
}

?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array()` will not return the single scalar value `1`, it will return an array.  Do something like `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($exists); if ($row[0] == 1) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

Your query return null so its showing login is incorrect. You only place email condition in where and fecth all the data like client password,name etc. May be your md5 encryption is different in both the condition.

Comment: Is there more than one type of md5?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($exists)) {
    ...
}
```

NOT:

```
if(mysqli_fetch_array($exists, MYSQL_NUM) === 1) {
    ...
}
```

[**mysqli_num_rows**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) documentation.

[**mysqli_fetch_array**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) returns an **array** that corresponds to the fetched row. Not what you're looking for in this case.

Comment: to clarify, if i do this the login form works but it always assumes it's correct, which is the opposite of the situation.

Comment: remove the COUNT(*) on the query make it like this SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '{$email}' AND pass = '{$pass}'")

and then you can do this one 

if(mysqli_num_rows($exists)) {
    ...
}

also try my answer

Comment: @Ramje your suggestions worked, thank you! However, while only correct ones pass login and wrong ones give invalid error, when it goes to index.php it has some issue with the cookie because it goes right back to login.php and says that i need to log in first but I already did!

Comment: try removing the md5, setcookie('pass', md5($_POST['pass']), time()+60*60*24*365);

make it like this setcookie('pass', $pass_without_md5, time()+60*60*24*365);

have you seen my answer? just remove the md5, only use md5 when saving it to the database

Answer (score 0):

```
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$exists = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE email = '{$email}' AND pass = '{$pass}'");
```

Its because  the $pass variable is on md5 and it would return no password match on the database.

try something like this

```
$pass_without_md5 = $_POST['pass'];
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
$exists = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM clients WHERE email = '{$email}' AND pass = '{$pass_without_md5}'");
```

**EDIT:**

```
<?php session_start();

require_once('db_connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['formsubmit']))
{       
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['email']);
 $pass_without_md5 = $_POST['pass'];
 $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
 $exists = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '{$email}' AND pass = '{$pass_without_md5}'"); 

 if(mysqli_num_rows($exists))
 {
  if (isset($_POST['rememberme'])) {
  setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], time()+60*60*24*365);
  setcookie('pass', $pass_without_md5 , time()+60*60*24*365);
  } 
  else {
  setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], false);
  setcookie('pass', $pass_without_md5, false);
  }

  header('Location: index.php');
 } 
 else {
    header('Location: login.php?error=1');
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: When I put that in:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/color/public_html/client/hostbill/login.php on line 12`

Comment: got it now i just missed the close parenthesis, you can copy the code again it would work this time

Comment: Great! With some modifications the code for login is working. Now how would I do logout?

Comment: a very simple solution is create another php, name it logout.php,, you just need to destroy the session and expire the cookies, dude you must do search the net alot of examples out there, can you also pls accept my answer, thanks